# Using Lucene in a clustered environment with shared NFS

Tags: lucene, locking, cluster-computing

I'm using Lucene 4.3.1 on a clustered Websphere environment. Both sides should share an index that is located on a shared NFS volume.

I keep getting the following stack trace:

```
Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/<pathToIndex>/write.lock
        org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/<pathToIndex>/write.lock
at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:84)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:667)
```

I use the following code to get the directory:

```
directory = FSDirectory.open( indexPath );
```

and i open and close the writers (on the clustermembers) in the methods of an ejb:

```
public void removeWikiDocument( long oid ) {
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter( directory, config );
    Term t = new Term( OID, Long.toString( oid ) );
    writer.deleteDocuments( t );
    writer.commit();
    writer.close();
}
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong respectively what is the right way to use in such a scenario.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answer, usage of NFS for a Lucene index is strongly discouraged as it badly hurts performance.
See this kind of discussion for more information:
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Lucene-index-on-NFS-td4011301.html

And there's a request feature to have full NFS support (which means handling delayed deletion):
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-33887

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for different JVM to access the same index in write mode. You could do this only with read-only indexes.

A lucene index must be managed by a single JVM.

If you want to deploy lucene in a clustered environnement you must have a look at [Lucene SolrCloud](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud) or [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue while using Lucene with Hibernate Search. In official Hibernate Search document, it is said that using Lucene in cluster mode with a shared file system is possible as explained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.1/reference/en-US/html/search-architecture.html#_lucene).

You have to make sure that *exclusive_index_use* value is *false* which specifies that the first node gains the index lock holds it until shutdown (by default it's true) as explained [here](http://goo.gl/f6VRu0). I think there should be a way to specify this setting also for Lucene without Hibernate Search.